# How to edit a text file with C++

Tags: c++, text-files, fstream

How do I edit a specific line of a text file in C++? Let's say I want to open a file and change the focus or pointer or whatever its called to line 17 column 20. That way I can edit text after line 17, column 20.

I tried this, but it didnt work.

```
ofstream txtFile("textFile.txt");
fseek(txtFile, 17, 20);
txtFile << "New stuff to enter at this point (overwrites old not insert)";
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fseek` is not seeking counting lines, but rather bytes. What you instruct the program is not to position the pointer at column 20 of 17th line, but rather at the 17 + 20 = 37th byte of the file.

The first parameter of the function is the origin, i.e. the count of bytes from the origin from which you count, and the second - how many more you offset.

See the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fseek/) of `fseek`.

I am not aware of any library that can do byte positioning in respect of lines and columns in C++. You will probably need to use a higher level function and parse lines one by one (e.g. using `getline` if you are after C++ solution).

Comment: It does. In your example First starts at byte 0, Line at byte 6, blah at byte 11 etc. You see: the `fseek` command does not understand anything of lines, sentences and words.

Comment: So is the byte count affected by the number of characters before it? if line 16 had like 6000 characters on it, would it change the byte count of line 17 column 20?

Comment: @JoshI: it will. With 6000. See my other comment

Comment: Well that throws a kink in my plans... ha. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This problem has a simple solution - implementatoin example below.

Answer (score 0):

Use fputs, like it's done [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fseek/). In order to recognize new lines, you have to loop through the content and count the newline characters (i.e.'\n' on linux). You can get the character currently pointed to with [getc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/getc/).

One way to implement this is to write a function that returns the byte-position of where a given row starts, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getRowPos(int row,FILE* fp){
  int pos=1,lines=1,currChr;
  do{
    currChr=getc(fp);
    if(currChr=='\n')
      lines++;
  }while(lines<row && currChr!=EOF && ++pos);
  return pos;
}
```

Using `fseek` one could then go to the position returned by `getRowPos` plus the column number (i.e. byte number, on the line), and then write the desired content using fputs, like so:

```
 int row=wanted row
 int col=wanted column

 FILE * pFile;
 //Open file for read and write                                                                        
 pFile = fopen ( "myfile.txt" , "rb+" );
 int rowPos=getRowPos(row,pFile);
 fseek ( pFile , rowPos+colPos , SEEK_SET );
 fputs ( "my new content" , pFile );
 fclose ( pFile );
```

If you know how wide your lines are, say n wide, you can add an `lseek` skipping n bytes ahead before the call to `getc`.

Comment: This is not going to do what the OP asks as pointed by my answer.

Comment: I added information about counting newline chars. It should work - and it will be better than reading whole lines as you suggest, in the cases where you have fixed width lines.

Comment: I am most glad to remove downvotes. I really hate placing them.